# I am getting a Dimension Error while writing a code for Vision Transformers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

```
#!pip install tensorflow-addons
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
```

My dataset is just a Parent folder with the name 'dataset' which has the 'Test' folder containing the test set images and 'training' folder which has the training images. In addition to test and training folder the code file is also there in the dataset folder.
[Click to see the file dataset directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SUB4.png)

```
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image
import os, shutil
from os import listdir
## Image Resizing
from PIL import Image

# load and display an image with Matplotlib
from matplotlib import image
from matplotlib import pyplot


# Image folder
images_dir = Path('Test/Images').expanduser()
images_dir

input_shape = (72, 72)

# Resizing all the images to same dimension
X_image_test = []
for fname in listdir(images_dir):
    fpath = os.path.join(images_dir, fname)
    im = Image.open(fpath)
    im_resized = im.resize(input_shape)
    X_image_test.append(im_resized)

## Converting the image to numpy array
X_image_test_array=[]
for x in range(len(X_image_test)):
    X_image=np.array(X_image_test[x],dtype='uint8')
    X_image_test_array.append(X_image)

# Checking the size of a single image
X_image_test_array[0].shape

#np.stack(X_image_array)


# Checking the size of a single image
#X_image_array[15].shape
```

The images that I have are just raw images without any kind of labels, just training and test images.

```
# Image folder
images_dir = Path('Training/Images').expanduser()
images_dir

input_shape = (72, 72)

# Resizing all the images to same dimension
X_image_train = []
for fname in listdir(images_dir):
    fpath = os.path.join(images_dir, fname)
    im = Image.open(fpath)
    im_resized = im.resize(input_shape)
    X_image_train.append(im_resized)

## Converting the image to numpy array
X_image_train_array=[]
for x in range(len(X_image_train)):
    X_image=np.array(X_image_train[x],dtype='uint8')
    X_image_train_array.append(X_image)

# Checking the size of a single image
print(X_image_train_array[0].shape)

#print(np.stack(X_image_train_array))


# Checking the size of a single image
print(X_image_train_array[15].shape)
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
X_image_train_array=tf.convert_to_tensor(X_image_train_array
    , dtype=None, dtype_hint=None, name=None
)
```

```
input_size = (72, 72)
batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "Training",
    #validation_split=0.2,
    #subset="training",
    seed=1337,
    image_size=input_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "Test",
    #validation_split=0.2,
    #subset="validation",
    seed=1337,
    image_size=input_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
```

```
learning_rate = 0.001
weight_decay = 0.0001
batch_size = 256
num_epochs = 15
image_size = 72  # We'll resize input images to this size
patch_size = 6  # Size of the patches to be extract from the input images
num_patches = (image_size // patch_size) ** 2
projection_dim = 64
num_heads = 4
transformer_units = [
    projection_dim * 2,
    projection_dim,
]  # Size of the transformer layers
transformer_layers = 8
mlp_head_units = [2048, 1024]  # Size of the dense layers of the final classifier
```

```
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Normalization(),
        layers.Resizing(image_size, image_size),
        layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
        layers.RandomRotation(factor=0.02),
        layers.RandomZoom(
            height_factor=0.2, width_factor=0.2
        ),
    ],
    name="data_augmentation",
)
# Compute the mean and the variance of the training data for normalization.
data_augmentation.layers[0].adapt(X_image_train_array)
```

```
def mlp(x, hidden_units, dropout_rate):
    for units in hidden_units:
        x = layers.Dense(units, activation=tf.nn.gelu)(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
    return x
```

```
class Patches(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, patch_size):
        super(Patches, self).__init__()
        self.patch_size = patch_size

    def call(self, images):
        batch_size = tf.shape(images)[0]
        patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
            images=images,
            sizes=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            strides=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
            padding="VALID",
        )
        patch_dims = patches.shape[-1]
        patches = tf.reshape(patches, [batch_size, -1, patch_dims])
        return patches
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()
plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
image = X_image_train_array[np.random.choice(range(X_image_train_array.shape[0]))]
plt.imshow(image.astype("uint8"))
plt.axis("off")

resized_image = tf.image.resize(
    tf.convert_to_tensor([image]), size=(image_size, image_size)
)
patches = Patches(patch_size)(resized_image)
print(f"Image size: {image_size} X {image_size}")
print(f"Patch size: {patch_size} X {patch_size}")
print(f"Patches per image: {patches.shape[1]}")
print(f"Elements per patch: {patches.shape[-1]}")

n = int(np.sqrt(patches.shape[1]))
plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
for i, patch in enumerate(patches[0]):
    ax = plt.subplot(n, n, i + 1)
    patch_img = tf.reshape(patch, (patch_size, patch_size, 3))
    plt.imshow(patch_img.numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.axis("off")
```

```
>>>Image size: 72 X 72
Patch size: 6 X 6
Patches per image: 144
Elements per patch: 108
```

```
class PatchEncoder(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_patches, projection_dim):
        super(PatchEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.num_patches = num_patches
        self.projection = layers.Dense(units=projection_dim)
        self.position_embedding = layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=num_patches, output_dim=projection_dim
        )

    def call(self, patch):
        positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=self.num_patches, delta=1)
        encoded = self.projection(patch) + self.position_embedding(positions)
        return encoded
```

```
def create_vit_classifier():
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    # Augment data.
    augmented = data_augmentation(inputs)
    # Create patches.
    patches = Patches(patch_size)(augmented)
    # Encode patches.
    encoded_patches = PatchEncoder(num_patches, projection_dim)(patches)

    # Create multiple layers of the Transformer block.
    for _ in range(transformer_layers):
        # Layer normalization 1.
        x1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(encoded_patches)
        # Create a multi-head attention layer.
        attention_output = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=projection_dim, dropout=0.1
        )(x1, x1)
        # Skip connection 1.
        x2 = layers.Add()([attention_output, encoded_patches])
        # Layer normalization 2.
        x3 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x2)
        # MLP.
        x3 = mlp(x3, hidden_units=transformer_units, dropout_rate=0.1)
        # Skip connection 2.
        encoded_patches = layers.Add()([x3, x2])

    # Create a [batch_size, projection_dim] tensor.
    representation = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(encoded_patches)
    representation = layers.Flatten()(representation)
    representation = layers.Dropout(0.5)(representation)
    # Add MLP.
    features = mlp(representation, hidden_units=mlp_head_units, dropout_rate=0.5)
    # Classify outputs.
    logits = layers.Dense(num_classes)(features)
    # Create the Keras model.
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=logits)
    return model
```

```
def run_experiment(model):
    optimizer = tfa.optimizers.AdamW(
        learning_rate=learning_rate, weight_decay=weight_decay
    )

    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=[
            keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name="accuracy"),
            keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(5, name="top-5-accuracy"),
        ],
    )

    checkpoint_filepath = "/tmp/checkpoint"
    checkpoint_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        checkpoint_filepath,
        monitor="val_accuracy",
        save_best_only=True,
        save_weights_only=True,
    )

    history = model.fit(
        x=x_train,
        y=y_train,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=num_epochs,
        validation_split=0.1,
        callbacks=[checkpoint_callback],
    )

    model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
    _, accuracy, top_5_accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
    print(f"Test accuracy: {round(accuracy * 100, 2)}%")
    print(f"Test top 5 accuracy: {round(top_5_accuracy * 100, 2)}%")

    return history
```

This is the error I am getting by running the last cell

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
   1879   try:
-> 1880     c_op = pywrap_tf_session.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1881   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 72 and 3 for '{{node data_augmentation/normalization/sub/sub}} = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT](Placeholder, data_augmentation/normalization/sub/y)' with input shapes: [?,72,72], [1,1,1,3].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
   1377             r_op = getattr(y, "__r%s__" % op_name)
-> 1378             out = r_op(x)
   1379             if out is NotImplemented:

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in r_binary_op_wrapper(y, x)
   1399       y, x = maybe_promote_tensors(y, x)
-> 1400       return func(x, y, name=name)
   1401 

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in subtract(x, y, name)
    547 def subtract(x, y, name=None):
--> 548   return gen_math_ops.sub(x, y, name)
    549 

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py in sub(x, y, name)
  10651   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
> 10652   _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
  10653         "Sub", x=x, y=y, name=name)

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    747       # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 748       op = g._create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
    749                                  name=scope, input_types=input_types,

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in _create_op_internal(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_device)
    598       captured_inputs.append(inp)
--> 599     return super(FuncGraph, self)._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    600         op_type, captured_inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def,

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _create_op_internal(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_device)
   3560     with self._mutation_lock():
-> 3561       ret = Operation(
   3562           node_def,

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in __init__(self, node_def, g, inputs, output_types, control_inputs, input_types, original_op, op_def)
   2040         op_def = self._graph._get_op_def(node_def.op)
-> 2041       self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, inputs,
   2042                                 control_input_ops, op_def)

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
   1882     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1883     raise ValueError(str(e))
   1884 

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 72 and 3 for '{{node data_augmentation/normalization/sub/sub}} = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT](Placeholder, data_augmentation/normalization/sub/y)' with input shapes: [?,72,72], [1,1,1,3].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6ee34a4aff67> in <module>
     38 
     39 
---> 40 vit_classifier = create_vit_classifier()
     41 history = run_experiment(vit_classifier)

<ipython-input-13-a790bd39a000> in create_vit_classifier()
      2     inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
      3     # Augment data.
----> 4     augmented = data_augmentation(inputs)
      5     # Create patches.
      6     patches = Patches(patch_size)(augmented)

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    974     # >> model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    975     if _in_functional_construction_mode(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list):
--> 976       return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
    977                                                 input_list)
    978 

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in _functional_construction_call(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list)
   1112         layer=self, inputs=inputs, build_graph=True, training=training_value):
   1113       # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
-> 1114       outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(
   1115           inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
   1116 

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call(self, inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
    846       return tf.nest.map_structure(keras_tensor.KerasTensor, output_signature)
    847     else:
--> 848       return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    849 
    850   def _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks):

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    886           self._maybe_build(inputs)
    887           inputs = self._maybe_cast_inputs(inputs)
--> 888           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    889 
    890         self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    381         kwargs['training'] = training
    382 
--> 383       outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)
    384 
    385       if len(tf.nest.flatten(outputs)) != 1:

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1035         with autocast_variable.enable_auto_cast_variables(
   1036             self._compute_dtype_object):
-> 1037           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
   1038 
   1039         if self._activity_regularizer:

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\keras\layers\preprocessing\normalization.py in call(self, inputs)
    250     # explicitly cast here to also allow integer inputs to be passed
    251     inputs = tf.cast(inputs, self.compute_dtype)
--> 252     return ((inputs - self.mean) /
    253             tf.maximum(tf.sqrt(self.variance), backend.epsilon()))
    254 

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
   1381             return out
   1382           except (TypeError, ValueError):
-> 1383             raise e
   1384         else:
   1385           raise

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
   1365         #   r_binary_op_wrapper use different force_same_dtype values.
   1366         x, y = maybe_promote_tensors(x, y, force_same_dtype=False)
-> 1367         return func(x, y, name=name)
   1368       except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
   1369         # Even if dispatching the op failed, the RHS may be a tensor aware

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in subtract(x, y, name)
    546 @dispatch.add_dispatch_support
    547 def subtract(x, y, name=None):
--> 548   return gen_math_ops.sub(x, y, name)
    549 
    550 

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py in sub(x, y, name)
  10650       pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
  10651   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
> 10652   _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
  10653         "Sub", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  10654   _result = _outputs[:]

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    746       # Add Op to graph
    747       # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 748       op = g._create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
    749                                  name=scope, input_types=input_types,
    750                                  attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in _create_op_internal(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_device)
    597       inp = self.capture(inp)
    598       captured_inputs.append(inp)
--> 599     return super(FuncGraph, self)._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    600         op_type, captured_inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def,
    601         compute_device)

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _create_op_internal(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_device)
   3559     # Session.run call cannot occur between creating and mutating the op.
   3560     with self._mutation_lock():
-> 3561       ret = Operation(
   3562           node_def,
   3563           self,

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in __init__(self, node_def, g, inputs, output_types, control_inputs, input_types, original_op, op_def)
   2039       if op_def is None:
   2040         op_def = self._graph._get_op_def(node_def.op)
-> 2041       self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, inputs,
   2042                                 control_input_ops, op_def)
   2043       name = compat.as_str(node_def.name)

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
   1881   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
   1882     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1883     raise ValueError(str(e))
   1884 
   1885   return c_op

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 72 and 3 for '{{node data_augmentation/normalization/sub}} = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT](Placeholder, data_augmentation/normalization/sub/y)' with input shapes: [?,72,72], [1,1,1,3].
```

​

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

In `create_vit_classifier()` the output of `inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)` is `KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 72, 72), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_12'), name='input_12', description="created by layer 'input_12'")`

When it gets to `augmented = data_augmentation(inputs)` it gives this error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "normalization_2" (type Normalization).

Dimensions must be equal, but are 72 and 4 for '{{node data_augmentation/normalization_2/sub}} = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT](Placeholder, data_augmentation/normalization_2/sub/y)' with input shapes: [?,72,72], [1,1,1,4].

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 72, 72), dtype=float32)
```

Now in a previous line:
`patch_img = tf.reshape(patch, (patch_size, patch_size, 3))`
I had to change the 3 to a 4 or I would get the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 144 values, but the requested shape has 108 [Op:Reshape]
```

This gives an output of:

```
Image size: 72 X 72
Patch size: 6 X 6
Patches per image: 144
Elements per patch: 144
```

for that particular cell.

Back to `create_vit_classifier()`...
Adding 72 to this line: `augmented = data_augmentation(72, inputs)` will get me all the way to `logits`.

I get the error:

```
     33     # Classify outputs.
---> 34     logits = layers.Dense(num_classes)(features)
     35     # Create the Keras model.
     36     model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=logits)

NameError: name 'num_classes' is not defined
```

So, your num_classes isn't defined and the problem lies within `create_vit_classifier()`

Edit:

I initialized `num_classes` to 14 (that was the output from earlier) and I can get the model to be created with `create_vit_classifier()` but it fails because `NameError: name 'x_train' is not defined` within `run_experiment()`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I will try to make the edits.